# How to build a specific package from a Debian source package?

Tags: debian, packaging

I'm testing a new locale-all package for my system, which comes with the drawback that the source is the gigantic glibc package. I'm estimating at least 1 hour for it to build, when the package I need is not even architecture dependent. Is there a way to build *only* that package or at very least only the `arch-indep` packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dpkg-buildpackage -A` (thanks, @WouterVerhelst)

> -A     Specifies a binary-only build, limited to architecture independent packages. Passed to dpkg-genchanges.

Also try `dpkg-buildpackage -T binary-indep`

> -T target - Calls `debian/rules target` after having setup the build  environment and  stops the package build process here.

[Debian Policy Manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html#s-debianrules) says:

> binary (required), binary-arch (required), binary-indep (required)
>
> The binary target must be all that is necessary for the user to build the binary package(s) produced from this source package. It is split into two parts: binary-arch builds the binary packages which are specific to a particular architecture, and binary-indep builds those which are not.

Some source packages (for example `apt`) have rules for building a specific package. So, you can run `dpkg-buildpackage -T apt-doc --as-root` to build only `apt-doc` package.

Comment: There is also `dpkg-buildpackage -A`, which is meant specifically for binary-indep packages. It works even if there is no `binary-indep` target (which is required today, but this wasn't always the case).

Comment: @WouterVerhelst, thanks for the info. `dpkg-buildpackage -A` runs `dpkg-source --before-build`, `clean`, `build-indep`, `binary-indep`, `dpkg-genchanges -A`, `dpkg-source --after-build`. This is the right answer:)

Comment: Updated my answer